# Теряется состояние при повторном обновление страницы React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hook

Народ помогите, не могу в хуках разобраться) делая какие либо изменения в коде(даже пробел поставить), после сохранения, запрос отрабатывает норм. Когда просто обновляю страницу после этого, useState как будто не успевает переписать состояние. В чем может быть проблема?

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import CompetitionMatchCard from '../../components/CompetitionMatchCard/CompetitionMatchCard'
import { useFetching } from '../../components/hooks/useFetching'
import Loader from '../../components/UI/Loader/Loader'
import ApiService from '../../http/api'

const CompetitionTeam = () => {
    const params = useParams()
    const [matches, setMatches] = useState(null)

    const fetchMatch = async (id) => {
        await axios.get(`https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/${id}/matches`, {
            headers: {
                'X-Auth-Token': process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN,
            }
        }).then(response => {
            setMatches(response.data)
        })
    }
    
    useEffect(() => { 
        fetchMatch(params.id) 
        // fetchCompetitionsMatches()
        console.log(matches)
    }, [])
    return ( 
        <div>
            {
                 <CompetitionMatchCard /> 
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default CompetitionTeam
```

[image: это после сохранения кода, ответ приходит]

[image: стоит просто обновить страницу]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответил сам на свой вопрос. В этой API было 2 запроса (204 и следом 200). При сохранение кода видимо приходил предыдущий ответ 200 и все данные было видно, а при перезагрузке опять приходил сначала 204 с пустым объектом и записывался в стейт.
При рендеринге на странице все отлично заработало. (я еще косякнул немного с JSX, не понимал почему map() отрабатывает не правильно).